# Как преобразовать массив в кортеж в C#?

Tags: c#, linq, tuple

Имеется список кортежей C# следующего вида:

```
List<(int, (double, double))> lightStabilizers;
```

Элементы списка должны вводиться с клавиатуры через `Console.ReadLine().Split()`. Полученный массив нужно как-то преобразовать в кортеж и добавить в список.

Как можно выполнить преобразование массива в кортеж? Пытаюсь это сделать через методы `System.Linq`, но не могу сориентироваться, куда смотреть

Comment: `Как можно выполнить преобразование массива в кортеж?` это как? Я не понял вопроса

Comment: @tym32167, через `Console.ReadLine().Split()` мы получаем массив из 3 строк, его надо преобразовать в кортеж указанного вида

Comment: `var s = Console.ReadLine().Split(); var tuple = (s[0], s[1], s[2]);`

Comment: linq тут вам не помощник, нет, можно наверное как-то извратиться, но по мне так проще руками написать, вам же еще и преобразование строк в числа нужно будет... а если пользователь перепутал точку и запятую в дробном числе или вместо нуля ввел О, или просто постучал по клавиатуре? Надо же вернуть ему информацию о том, где и в чем он не прав

Comment: ну или `var tuple = ( int.Parse(s[0]), ( double.Parse(s[1]), double.Parse(s[2])));`

Comment: @tym32167 оно конечно да, но какой именно Parse выбросил исключение на чем гадать будем? Даже для учебного проекта не стал бы так делать. Да я зануда =)

Comment: @rdorn а какая разница, какой именно выкинул исключение? В смысле, допустим, второй. Чем это нам поможет?

Comment: @tym32167 ну как минимум указать пользователю на конкретную ошибку при вводе, как теоретический максимум - при работе с автоматизированным вводом - диагностика последнего. Стандартные XML и JSON парсеры возвращают же зачем-то (понятно зачем) подробный ответ где косяк, чем данная задача принципиально отличается мне не понятно.

Comment: Количество и тип элементов кортежа (должны быть) известны на этапе компиляции. Поэтому создавать/заполнять его только вручную, как уже написали выше.

Comment: @rdorn ну разница только в том, что там мы укажем конкретную строку, тут будет одна строка для всех трех вызовов. Но в любом случае придется смотреть на данные, а они рядом назодятся, так как парсятся с одной и той же строки. Потому, имхо, разницы нет. Вот если бы они как от по отдельности вводились, то да, есть смысл

Comment: @tym32167 согласен, это уже вкусовщина, тогда может ответом?

Comment: @rdorn done. Если есть желание, можете ваш вариант просто добавить в мой ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас строка на входе

```
var s = Console.ReadLine().Split();
```

То конвертировать её в кортеж вы можете вот так

```
var tuple = (int.Parse(s[0]), (double.Parse(s[1]), double.Parse(s[2])));
```